# Integrating Google Drive into Android app, unresolved imports

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to integrate google drive api within my app.
I followed step-by-step this quick start guide https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android but after lot of tests, I still have some unresolved imports!
I have all imports working, except:

- the `com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions` package and
- the `com.google.api.client.extensions` package

I'm sure there's something wrong with my project configuration:
I have added the Drive API v2, the google play services jar file as shown in the guide, and I'm using Google APIs for Android 4.2 as build target, but I still have unresolved imports for the `extensions` packages.

In my eclipse configuration everything is up-to-dated.

Can anyone help me? Or have the same issue?

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial step #3 to add Google APIs from Eclipse?

Comment: I followed correctly every step of the tutorial, but since the problem was solved in the new api revision, it seems it was just an api issue. I think there should be no other problems, now.

Answer (score 0):

The new revision of Google Drive Api v2 solved the problem. I have received the update 2 days ago, and then the imports started to work automatically.
The working version I'm using right now is `drive-v2r33`